# How to set values in a bidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array, google-sheets

First of all, sorry about my skills; my coding background is zero and I am just trying to modify an script to fit my needs.

I need to `setValues` in a two-rows datasheet data range.

The current script sets the values in the first row.
How should I modify the script so I can get the data from my 4 values in 2 rows?

Current behaviour:

[image: current]

My go-to behaviour:

[image: go-to]

**Function to run: Print**

```
function Print() {

   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet").getRange(1, 1, 1, 2).setValues(Data());    

}

function Data() {

    var array = [];

                      var score = "retrieved score";
                      var time = (2+2);
                      var device = "device";
                      var speed = 3+3;

    array.push([score,time]);

    Utilities.sleep(1000);

    return array;
}
```

Comment: Expand range that you get via `getRange()` - currently, you only get first row, first column, **one row**, wo columns (hence the parameters 1,1,1,2)

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work.  I set getRange(1, 1, 2, 2) and then array.push([score,time,device,speed])    but I get this error: "The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 2."

Comment: oh, an yes, sure - you need to make sure that each row has only two columns - currently you create a one-row, two-col matrix, and you need to `[ [score, time], [device, speed] ]` ofc

Comment: Just updated this line: `array.push( [[score,time],[device,speed]] );` but I guess I need to redefine the var because `var array = [];` seems a one row-one col matrix.  I am unsucessfully trying to define the  var :-(   .

Comment: I meant `[[  ]]` as a whole, of course you should only `push` two rows in the `array`, not the matrix I mentioned. Please, read up on how `push()` method [works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

Trying to set 2 x 2 matrix of values to 1 x 2 range

**Solution**

Your values have to match dimensions of the range. The sheet is a matrix consisting of cells:

```
|       |       col 1       | col 2 |
| ----- | ----------------- | ----- |
| row 1 | "retrieved score" |   4   |
| row 2 | "device"          |   6   |
```

2-dimensional arrays are basically the same, where outer level represents rows and inner - columns:

```
[
  [ "retrieved score", 4 ],
  [ "device", 6 ]
]
```

Thus, with a simple modification, the cells should be filled correctly:

```
function Print() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  const rng = ss.getSheetByName("sheet").getRange(1, 1, 2, 2);

  const values = Data();

  rng.setValues(values);    

}

function Data() {

  var array = [];

  var score = "retrieved score";
  var time = 2+2;
  var device = "device";
  var speed = 3+3;

  array.push([score, time], [device, speed]);

  Utilities.sleep(1000);

  return array;
}
```

**Notes**

1. It does not make sense to me that you need to use the `sleep()` utility method here. Operations on an in-memory array are synchronous and atomic (which is not true for `setValues`, as it is an I/O operation).

**References**

1. `push()` method [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) on MDN
2. `setValues()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: Thank you, this is as good as it gets.  The code is not mine, I can't code, but I think `sleep()` is there because in the real project `setValues` is within a print function where a loop changes data and range . So, maybe, `sleep()` is needed to make work both functions. Does it make sense?

Comment: @Lolo - thank you for the feedback. No worries - just curious. Yes, that makes sense, but not in `Data()` as it has nothing to do with input / output ( i.e. `setValues()`,  which, alongside giving a database time to propagate changes, is one of the main uses of `slepp`) - the `setValues()` method will use the *result* of the `Data()` call, so you are waisting a full second. It belongs to *after* the `setValues()` call and only if the script depends on changes to propagate (but that's what [`flush`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) is for)